# Get the difference between dates in terms of weeks, months, quarters, and years

Tags: r, date

I have two dates let´s say `14.01.2013` and `26.03.2014`.

I would like to get the difference between those two dates in terms of weeks(?), months(in the example 14), quarters(4) and years(1).

Do you know the best way to get this?

Comment: For the weeks I found the following difftime(time1,time2,units="weeks"). This is unfortunately not working for months, quarters, years.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

what about this:

```
# get difference between dates `"01.12.2013"` and `"31.12.2013"`

# weeks
difftime(strptime("26.03.2014", format = "%d.%m.%Y"),
strptime("14.01.2013", format = "%d.%m.%Y"),units="weeks")
Time difference of 62.28571 weeks

# months
(as.yearmon(strptime("26.03.2014", format = "%d.%m.%Y"))-
as.yearmon(strptime("14.01.2013", format = "%d.%m.%Y")))*12
[1] 14

# quarters
(as.yearqtr(strptime("26.03.2014", format = "%d.%m.%Y"))-
as.yearqtr(strptime("14.01.2013", format = "%d.%m.%Y")))*4
[1] 4

# years
year(strptime("26.03.2014", format = "%d.%m.%Y"))-
year(strptime("14.01.2013", format = "%d.%m.%Y"))
[1] 1
```

`as.yearmon()` and `as.yearqtr()` are in package `zoo`. `year()` is in package `lubridate`.
What do you think?

Comment: This answer requires caution... it will consider Dec 31 2013 to be 1 year different from the next day, Jan 1, 2014. Sometimes this is wanted, but often not.

Comment: Extending Gregor's caveat: `year` will give difference in **calendar years only**, so if you need to know the difference in some fraction of a year, it will not be suitable.

Comment: 'format' + defaults can make this easier to type:

    difftime(format("2014-03-26"), format("2013-01-14"), units = "weeks")
    Time difference of 62.28571 weeks

Answer (score 61):

All the existing answers are imperfect (IMO) and either make assumptions about the desired output or don't provide flexibility for the desired output.

Based on the examples from the OP, and the OP's stated expected answers, I think these are the answers you are looking for (plus some additional examples that make it easy to extrapolate).

(This only requires base R and doesn't require zoo or lubridate)

**Convert to Datetime Objects**

```
date_strings = c("14.01.2013", "26.03.2014")
datetimes = strptime(date_strings, format = "%d.%m.%Y") # convert to datetime objects
```

**Difference in Days**

You can use the diff in days to get some of our later answers

```
diff_in_days = difftime(datetimes[2], datetimes[1], units = "days") # days
diff_in_days
#Time difference of 435.9583 days
```

**Difference in Weeks**

Difference in weeks is a special case of `units = "weeks"` in `difftime()`

```
diff_in_weeks = difftime(datetimes[2], datetimes[1], units = "weeks") # weeks
diff_in_weeks
#Time difference of 62.27976 weeks
```

Note that this is the same as dividing our diff_in_days by 7 (7 days in a week)

```
as.double(diff_in_days)/7
#[1] 62.27976
```

**Difference in Years**

With similar logic, we can derive years from diff_in_days

```
diff_in_years = as.double(diff_in_days)/365 # absolute years
diff_in_years
#[1] 1.194406
```

You seem to be expecting the diff in years to be "1", so I assume you just want to count absolute calendar years or something, which you can easily do by using `floor()`

```
# get desired output, given your definition of 'years'
floor(diff_in_years)
#[1] 1
```

**Difference in Quarters**

```
# get desired output for quarters, given your definition of 'quarters'
floor(diff_in_years * 4)
#[1] 4
```

**Difference in Months**

Can calculate this as a conversion from diff_years

```
# months, defined as absolute calendar months (this might be what you want, given your question details)
months_diff = diff_in_years*12
floor(month_diff)
#[1] 14
```

I know this question is old, but given that I still had to solve this problem just now, I thought I would add my answers. Hope it helps.

Comment: I think this does not work, when the `months_diff` is < 0.

Comment: @timat can you give a specific example of two date strings for which this doesn't work for you?

Comment: `date_strings = c("14.07.2014", "10.03.2015")` give `-4` instead  7 months according to the first definition..

Comment: @timat you're right! I'm not sure why when I wrote this I didn't just calculate months directly from the `diff_in_years`, e.g., in your example, the true answer is that almost 8 full months have past. You get the correct answer just by `diff_in_years*12 = 7.857534`
I corrected my answer--thanks.

Comment: Remember when you divide days by `365` to get years, it only applies to 3 out of 4 years, due to leap years. Dividing by `365.25` would be more precise, especially for calculating an age.

Answer (score 15):

For weeks, you can use function `difftime`:

```
date1 <- strptime("14.01.2013", format="%d.%m.%Y")
date2 <- strptime("26.03.2014", format="%d.%m.%Y")
difftime(date2,date1,units="weeks")
Time difference of 62.28571 weeks
```

But `difftime` doesn't work with duration over weeks.
The following is a very suboptimal solution using `cut.POSIXt` for those durations but you can work around it:

```
seq1 <- seq(date1,date2, by="days")
nlevels(cut(seq1,"months"))
15
nlevels(cut(seq1,"quarters"))
5
nlevels(cut(seq1,"years"))
2
```

This is however the number of months, quarters or years spanned by your time interval and not the duration of your time interval expressed in months, quarters, years (since  those do not have a constant duration). Considering the comment you made on @SvenHohenstein answer I would think you can use `nlevels(cut(seq1,"months")) - 1` for what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 14):

I just wrote this for another question, then stumbled here.

```
library(lubridate)

#' Calculate age
#' 
#' By default, calculates the typical "age in years", with a
#' \code{floor} applied so that you are, e.g., 5 years old from
#' 5th birthday through the day before your 6th birthday. Set
#' \code{floor = FALSE} to return decimal ages, and change \code{units}
#' for units other than years.
#' @param dob date-of-birth, the day to start calculating age.
#' @param age.day the date on which age is to be calculated.
#' @param units unit to measure age in. Defaults to \code{"years"}. Passed to \link{\code{duration}}.
#' @param floor boolean for whether or not to floor the result. Defaults to \code{TRUE}.
#' @return Age in \code{units}. Will be an integer if \code{floor = TRUE}.
#' @examples
#' my.dob <- as.Date('1983-10-20')
#' age(my.dob)
#' age(my.dob, units = "minutes")
#' age(my.dob, floor = FALSE)
age <- function(dob, age.day = today(), units = "years", floor = TRUE) {
    calc.age = interval(dob, age.day) / duration(num = 1, units = units)
    if (floor) return(as.integer(floor(calc.age)))
    return(calc.age)
}
```

Usage examples:

```
my.dob <- as.Date('1983-10-20')

age(my.dob)
# [1] 31

age(my.dob, floor = FALSE)
# [1] 31.15616

age(my.dob, units = "minutes")
# [1] 16375680

age(seq(my.dob, length.out = 6, by = "years"))
# [1] 31 30 29 28 27 26
```

Comment: 'new_interval' is deprecated; use 'interval' instead. Deprecated in version '1.5.0'.

Comment: *I just wrote this for another question, then stumbled here.* Me too! Small advice: use curly brackets after an if statement: `if (floor) { ... }` and only use `return` when you're returning something halfway your function. Last line should just be `calc.age`.

Comment: @MSBerends Those are just style guidelines. I much prefer to explicitly `return` with my functions - I find it clearer. Of course, in your own code, use whatever style suits you.

Comment: Very true. Regarding the function: it doesn’t work right in this case: `1950-01-17` and `2015-01-01`. It returns `65`, but this person would not turn 65 before 2015-01-17... Any idea why?

Comment: That's strange! I'll look into it more. The problem seems to be 2013, if you define `yy = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2010-01-01"), to = as.Date("2015-01-01"), by = "year")` and then try `age(dob = as.Date("1950-01-17"), age.day = yy)`, the result jumps over 62. And only if the DOB is between 1949 and 1952. Very strange...

Comment: How coincidental then, that I just had a patient with such a birth day and test date! I'll see too if I can manage things here.

Comment: For future reference: This doesn't happen with the current version of lubridate 1.7.8 (https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/news/index.html). The reason was the use of duration in this function. Previoulsy, a year was considered 365, and not 365.25 days.`d <- as.integer(as.duration(interval(as.Date("1950-01-17"), as.Date("2015-01-01"))))`;
`d/(86400*365)
#> 65`;
`d/(86400*365.25)
#> 64.95551` ...

Comment: (Having said that, your function is great, but I'd probably also include the option of using periods. Just to make it a bit more complex :)

Answer (score 11):

Here the still lacking `lubridate` answer (although [Gregor's function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27364453/7941188) is built on this package)

The [lubridate timespan documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lubridate/versions/1.7.4/topics/timespan) is very helpful for understanding the difference between periods and duration. I also like the [lubridate cheatsheet](https://rawgit.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/master/lubridate.pdf) and [this very useful thread](https://data.library.virginia.edu/working-with-dates-and-time-in-r-using-the-lubridate-package/)

```r
library(lubridate)

dates <- c(dmy('14.01.2013'), dmy('26.03.2014'))

span <- dates[1] %--% dates[2] #creating an interval object

#creating period objects 
as.period(span, unit = 'year') 
#> [1] "1y 2m 12d 0H 0M 0S"
as.period(span, unit = 'month')
#> [1] "14m 12d 0H 0M 0S"
as.period(span, unit = 'day')
#> [1] "436d 0H 0M 0S"
```

Periods do not accept weeks as units. But you can convert *durations* to weeks:

```
as.duration(span)/ dweeks(1)
#makes duration object (in seconds) and divides by duration of a week (in seconds)
#> [1] 62.28571
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 6):

Here's a solution:

```
dates <- c("14.01.2013", "26.03.2014")

# Date format:
dates2 <- strptime(dates, format = "%d.%m.%Y")

dif <- diff(as.numeric(dates2)) # difference in seconds

dif/(60 * 60 * 24 * 7) # weeks
[1] 62.28571
dif/(60 * 60 * 24 * 30) # months
[1] 14.53333
dif/(60 * 60 * 24 * 30 * 3) # quartes
[1] 4.844444
dif/(60 * 60 * 24 * 365) # years
[1] 1.194521
```

Comment: Thanks for that however your solution will not work in all cases. For example if you take dates <- c("01.12.2013", "31.12.2013"), you´ll get difference in months=1 while I would expect the difference to be 0 (both dates occur in Dec 13).

Comment: Although still nog accurate, I suggest using 365.242 for the amount of days in a year instead of 365.

Answer (score 3):

This is a simple way to find out the difference in years with the `lubridate` package:

```
as.numeric(as.Date("14-03-2013", format = "%d-%m-%Y") %--% as.Date("23-03-2014", format = "%d-%m-%Y"), "years")
```

This returns 1.023956

You can use `floor()` if you don't want the decimals.

Comment: This also works if you are calculating the interval between two date columns, or a date column and a fixed date. Just replace the as.Date(...) brackets with the variable names.

Answer (score 2):

try this for a months solution

```
StartDate <- strptime("14 January 2013", "%d %B %Y") 
EventDates <- strptime(c("26 March 2014"), "%d %B %Y") 
difftime(EventDates, StartDate)
```

Comment: Hi Rachel, thanky for that however this is not working. When I run strptime("14 January 2013", "%d %B %Y") I get NA.

Comment: Same here.. If I use this step, I get NAs

Comment: This solution will work only for English locales. It's much safer to use `%m` and numeric months (e.g. 1 for January) instead of `%B`.

Answer (score 2):

A more "precise" calculation. That is, the number of week/month/quarter/year for a non-complete week/month/quarter/year is the fraction of calendar days in that week/month/quarter/year. For example, the number of months between 2016-02-22 and 2016-03-31 is 8/29 + 31/31 = 1.27586

explanation inline with code

```
#' Calculate precise number of periods between 2 dates
#' 
#' @details The number of week/month/quarter/year for a non-complete week/month/quarter/year 
#'     is the fraction of calendar days in that week/month/quarter/year. 
#'     For example, the number of months between 2016-02-22 and 2016-03-31 
#'     is 8/29 + 31/31 = 1.27586
#' 
#' @param startdate start Date of the interval
#' @param enddate end Date of the interval
#' @param period character. It must be one of 'day', 'week', 'month', 'quarter' and 'year'
#' 
#' @examples 
#' identical(numPeriods(as.Date("2016-02-15"), as.Date("2016-03-31"), "month"), 15/29 + 1)
#' identical(numPeriods(as.Date("2016-02-15"), as.Date("2016-03-31"), "quarter"), (15 + 31)/(31 + 29 + 31))
#' identical(numPeriods(as.Date("2016-02-15"), as.Date("2016-03-31"), "year"), (15 + 31)/366)
#' 
#' @return exact number of periods between
#' 
numPeriods <- function(startdate, enddate, period) {

    numdays <- as.numeric(enddate - startdate) + 1
    if (grepl("day", period, ignore.case=TRUE)) {
        return(numdays)

    } else if (grepl("week", period, ignore.case=TRUE)) {
        return(numdays / 7)
    }

    #create a sequence of dates between start and end dates
    effDaysinBins <- cut(seq(startdate, enddate, by="1 day"), period)

    #use the earliest start date of the previous bins and create a breaks of periodic dates with
    #user's period interval
    intervals <- seq(from=as.Date(min(levels(effDaysinBins)), "%Y-%m-%d"), 
        by=paste("1",period), 
        length.out=length(levels(effDaysinBins))+1)

    #create a sequence of dates between the earliest interval date and last date of the interval
    #that contains the enddate
    allDays <- seq(from=intervals[1],
        to=intervals[intervals > enddate][1] - 1,
        by="1 day")

    #bin all days in the whole period using previous breaks
    allDaysInBins <- cut(allDays, intervals)

    #calculate ratio of effective days to all days in whole period
    sum( tabulate(effDaysinBins) / tabulate(allDaysInBins) )
} #numPeriods
```

Please let me know if you find more boundary cases where the above solution does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Hoping I can add something new to the table that's simple, intuitive and efficient.

Using `time_diff()` from my package `timeplyr`, one can easily calculate the time difference between any 2 date/datetime vectors.

```r
# remotes::install_github("NicChr/timeplyr")
library(timeplyr)
library(lubridate)

x <- dmy("14-01-2013")
y <- dmy("26-03-2014")

time_diff(x, y, "days")
#> [1] 436
time_diff(x, y, "hours")
#> [1] 10464
time_diff(x, y, "weeks")
#> [1] 62.28571
time_diff(x, y, "months")
#> [1] 14.3871
time_diff(x, y, "years")
#> [1] 1.194521
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

You can specify exotic units as well.

```r
.extra_time_units
#>  [1] "fortnights" "quarters"   "semesters"  "olympiads"  "lustrums"  
#>  [6] "decades"    "indictions" "scores"     "centuries"  "milleniums"

time_diff(x, y, "fortnight")
#> [1] 31.14286
time_diff(x, y, "quarter")
#> [1] 4.788889
time_diff(x, y, "decade")
#> [1] 0.1193866
```

Choose between lubridate `durations` and `periods`.

```r
time_diff(x, y, dmonths(1))
#> [1] 14.32444
time_diff(x, y, months(1))
#> [1] 14.3871
```

And even choose multi-units, as it's vectorised.

```r
time_diff(x, y, time_by = list("days" = -10:10))
#>  [1]  -43.60000  -48.44444  -54.50000  -62.28571  -72.66667  -87.20000
#>  [7] -109.00000 -145.33333 -218.00000 -436.00000        Inf  436.00000
#> [13]  218.00000  145.33333  109.00000   87.20000   72.66667   62.28571
#> [19]   54.50000   48.44444   43.60000
```