# Select a value from time series by date in R

Tags: r, time-series

How to select a value from time series corresponding needed date?

I create a monthly time series object with command:

```
producers.price <- ts(producers.price, start=2012+0/12, frequency=12)
```

Then I try to do next:

```
value <- producers.price[as.Date("01.2015", "%m.%Y")]
```

But this doesn't make that I want and value is equal

```
[1] NA
```

Instead of `10396.8212805739` if producers.price is:

```
producers.price <- structure(c(7481.52109434237, 6393.18959031561, 6416.63065650718, 
                  5672.08354710121, 7606.24186413516, 5201.59247092013, 6488.18361474813, 
                  8376.39182893415, 9199.50916585545, 8261.87133079494, 8293.8195347453, 
                  8233.13630279516, 7883.17272003961, 7537.21001580393, 6566.60260432381, 
                  7119.99345843556, 8086.40101607729, 9125.11104610046, 10134.0228610828, 
                  10834.5732454454, 9410.35031874371, 9559.36933274129, 9952.38679679724, 
                  10390.3628690951, 11134.8432864557, 11652.0075507499, 12626.9616107684, 
                  12140.6698452193, 11336.8315981684, 10526.0309052316, 10632.1492109584, 
                  8341.26367412737, 9338.95688558448, 9732.80173656971, 10724.5525831506, 
                  11272.2273444623, 10396.8212805739, 10626.8428853062, 11701.0802817581, 
                  NA), .Tsp = c(2012, 2015.25, 12), class = "ts")
```

Comment: Some reproducible data would help you get an answer quicker and more verifiable.

Comment: It looks like your are subsetting values that do not exist. Values are prices, in this case your data seems to be a series of prices of class ts and so with attributes tsp. Why don't you create a data frame with dates in one column and prices in another? subsetting would be much easier in my opinion.

Comment: as.Date does not support dates that consist of only a month and a year, thus `as.Date("01.2015", "%m.%Y")` returns a NULL value. This post may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242955/converting-year-and-month-to-a-date-in-r

Comment: SabDeM, you absolutely right that this will be easier with dataframe. But for my program it seems better to tackle the task without dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I had/have a similar problem and was looking all over to solve it. My solution is not as great as I'd have wanted it to be, but it works. I tried it out with your data and it seems to give the right result.

**Explanation**

Turns out in R time series data is really stored as a sequence, starting at 1, and not with yout T. Eg. If you have a time series that starts in 1950 and ends in 1960 with each data at one year interval, the Y at 1950 will be ts[1] and Y at 1960 will be ts[11].
Based on this logic you will need to subtract the date from the start of the data and add 1 to get the value at that point.

This code in R gives you the result you expect.

```
producers.price[((as.yearmon("2015-01")- as.yearmon("2012-01"))*12)+1]
```

If you need help in the time calculations, check this answer
You will need the `zoo` and `lubridate` packages 
[Get the difference between dates in terms of weeks, months, quarters, and years](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14454476/get-the-difference-between-dates-in-terms-of-weeks-months-quarters-and-years)

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

**1) window.ts**

The `window.ts` function is used to subset a `"ts"` time series by a time window.  The window command produces a time series with one data point and the [[1]] makes it a straight numeric value:

```
window(producers.price, start = 2015 + 0/12, end = 2015 + 0/12)[[1]]
## [1] 10396.82
```

**2) zoo**  We can alternately convert it to zoo and subscript it by a yearmon class variable and then use [[1]] or `coredata` to convert it to a plain number or we can use `window.zoo` much as we did with `window.ts` :

```
library(zoo)

as.zoo(producers.price)[as.yearmon("2015-01")][[1]]
## [1] 10396.82

coredata(as.zoo(producers.price)[as.yearmon("2015-01")])
## [1] 10396.82

window(as.zoo(producers.price), 2015 + 0/12 )[[1]]
## [1] 10396.82

coredata(window(as.zoo(producers.price), 2015 + 0/12 ))
## [1] 10396.82
```

**3) xts** The four lines in (2) also work if `library(zoo)` is replaced with `library(xts)` and `as.zoo` is replaced with `as.xts`.

Answer (score 0):

Looking for a simple command, one line and no library needed?
You might try this.

```
as.numeric(window(producers.price, 2015.1, 2015.2))
```