# how to calculate month difference in R

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I have dates of format `2015-03` (i.e year-month). Now I want to calculate the month difference in between 2 dates.

Example: difference between dates `2015-03` and `2014-12` should be 3 or 4 as December to March is 3 months or 4 months depending on whether we consider December or not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the difference between dates in terms of weeks, months, quarters, and years](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14454476/get-the-difference-between-dates-in-terms-of-weeks-months-quarters-and-years)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a <- "2015-03"
b <- "2014-12"
a <- unlist(strsplit(a, "-"))
b <- unlist(strsplit(b, "-"))
a <- (as.numeric(a[1])*12) + as.numeric(a[2])
b <- (as.numeric(b[1])*12) + as.numeric(b[2])
difference <- diff(c(b,a))
difference
```

The result of this is 3

Answer (score 5):

You can do it via `diff`

```
require(lubridate)
a <- c("2015-03","2014-12")
a_parsed <- ymd(paste0(a,"-01")) # There might be a nicer solution to get the dates

diff(year(a_parsed)) * 12 + diff(month(a_parsed)) # Results in 3
```

Use `+ 1` to "consider December"

Explanation:
`diff(year(a_parsed))` gives you the difference in the years, `* 12` the month resulting from this. `diff(month(a_parsed))` results in the monthly difference, ignoring the yearly difference. Combined it results in the Monthly difference you asked for.

Comment: thank you Floo0, though I used strptime according to my code and variable.....I did use your idea :)