# How to add new column in R during for loop?

Tags: r

I wanted to find the age in the database, I used this answer to solve the problem [Get the difference between dates in terms of weeks, months, quarters, and years?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14454476/get-the-difference-between-dates-in-terms-of-weeks-months-quarters-and-years/29785779#29785779)

This code I used to find years

```
age <- function(dob, age.day = today(), units = "years", floor = TRUE) {
  calc.age = interval(dob, age.day) / duration(num = 1, units = units)
  if (floor) return(as.integer(floor(calc.age)))
  return(calc.age)
}
```

But when I am performing loop using for loop and trying to save value in new column in database customer, I am not able to do so.

```
for (i in customer$dateofbirth) {
  as.Date(i)
  customer$age <- age(i)
}
```

The result I am getting is same value in age column. Where I am going wrong?

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: I understand but I am doing course where they share there database in remote computer with no internet access. I will try to edit my question as much as I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
customer <- customer %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(age = age(as.Date(dateofbirth)))
```

Comment: Its coming "character string is not in a standard umambigious format"

Comment: It's not possible to troubleshoot further without some example data. See the comment in your question.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `for` loop, maybe this is helpful

```
for (i in customer$dateofbirth) 
 customer$age[i] <- age(as.Date(i))
```

@RHertel thanks for the comment `age(as.Date(i))`

Comment: @RHertel : Thanks for the comment. I overlooked that.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm not sure that this works, though. The OP hasn't provided a reproducible example.