# R loop on data frame

Tags: r

I am working on a data frame which I named 'data'

I need to calculate the weighted mean age for each study, that is to say for each row. I can use the following set of functions:

`weighted.mean(x=data[1,7:8],w=data[1,5:6])`
`weighted.mean(x=data[1,7:8],w=data[1,5:6])`
`weighted.mean(x=data[2,7:8],w=data[2,5:6])`
`weighted.mean(x=data[3,7:8],w=data[3,5:6])`
`weighted.mean(x=data[4,7:8],w=data[4,5:6])`
`weighted.mean(x=data[5,7:8],w=data[5,5:6])`
`weighted.mean(x=data[6,7:8],w=data[6,5:6])`

Is it possible to create some kind of loop so that I don't have to write six commands but just one and then attach the results as a new column in my data frame ? Many thanks for your help

Comment: Sure, have a look at `help("for")` or the [section on for loops in An Introduction to R](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Repetitive-execution). Then try it out. Maybe look at [similar questions on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38429826/903061). Come here and ask a question when you've tried and gotten stuck - show us your code and we'll help fix it. Don't come here before trying expecting a custom introduction and tutorial. Such basic questions are actually impossible to answer well without seeing attempt because it's not clear what you don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Gregor as pointed out, it's very basic, and you should try to find answers in the help manual and hundreds of tutorials available on online. Anyway, this should help you.

```
 for(i in 1:7) {
    weighted.mean(x=data[i,7:8],w=data[i,5:6])
 }
```

People usually downvote questions without proper research. Better do some homework next time. All the best.