# R: For a timespan of some years compute the mean of measured values in every calendary month

Tags: r, date

I got a `data.frame` like the one at the end (df) that I found [here](http://open-research-data.ext.zalf.de/ResearchData/2000_266.html). I want to calculate the mean of e.g. `df$PH` for every month. I messed around quite a while and ended up with the following (with help from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14454476/get-the-difference-between-dates-in-terms-of-weeks-months-quarters-and-years)):

```
library(lubridate)
library(zoo)

# Get first month where measuremets have taken place
first <- floor_date(min(df$TIME), unit = "months")

# Calculate number of (calendary) months between first and last measurement
num.months <- ceiling(abs(as.yearmon(strptime(min(df$TIME), format = "%Y-%m-%d"))
                          - as.yearmon(strptime(max(df$TIME), format = "%Y-%m-%d"))) * 12)

# Calculate means of pH in every (calendary) month
my <- c()
for(i in 1:num.months){
  mon <- interval(start = first %m+% months(i - 1), end = first %m+% months(i))
  my <- c(my, mean(df[which(df$TIME %within% mon), "PH"], na.rm = T))
}
```

I think there is most probably an easier solution. Something like:

```
for(months in interval("2000-07-26", "2014-03-06")){
  mean(df[which(df$TIME %within% months), "PH"])
}
```

Do you know any?
(Otherwise people can at least find this one.)

---

```
df <- structure(list(TIME = structure(c(11164, 11296, 11296, 11296, 
11330, 11330, 11547, 11547, 11547, 11547, 11639, 11639, 11639, 
11639, 11758, 11758, 11758, 11758, 11869, 11869, 11869, 11869, 
11968, 11968, 11968, 11968, 12009, 12009, 12009, 12102, 12102, 
12102, 12102, 12102, 12193, 12193, 12193, 12193, 12193, 12193, 
12193, 12282, 12282, 12282, 12282, 12282, 12282, 12368, 12368, 
12368, 12368, 12500, 12500, 12500, 12500, 12500, 12500, 12500, 
12590, 12590, 12590, 12590, 12590, 12590, 12590, 12684, 12684, 
12684, 12684, 12684, 12800, 12800, 12800, 12800, 12800, 12891, 
12891, 12891, 12891, 12891, 12891, 12891, 12998, 12998, 12998, 
12998, 13101, 13101, 13101, 13101, 13101, 13273, 13273, 13273, 
13273, 13362, 13362, 13362, 13362, 13459, 13459, 13459, 13459, 
13459, 13459, 13557, 13557, 13557, 13557, 13557, 13557, 13557, 
13654, 13654, 13654, 13654, 13654, 13654, 13767, 13767, 13767, 
13767, 13767, 13767, 13767, 13857, 13857, 13857, 13857, 13857, 
13857, 13857, 13949, 13949, 13949, 13949, 13949, 13949, 13949, 
14048, 14048, 14048, 14048, 14048, 14048, 14048, 14398, 14398, 
14398, 14398, 14398, 14755, 14755, 14755, 14755, 14755, 14755, 
14755, 14943, 14943, 14943, 14943, 14943, 14943, 15806, 15806, 
15806, 15806, 15806, 15806, 15806, 16135, 16135, 16135, 16135, 
16135, 16135), class = "Date"), GAUGE_ID = c(198L, 200L, 199L, 
198L, 202L, 198L, 204L, 198L, 203L, 201L, 203L, 204L, 201L, 198L, 
201L, 198L, 203L, 204L, 203L, 201L, 204L, 198L, 203L, 204L, 201L, 
198L, 199L, 202L, 200L, 203L, 201L, 204L, 198L, 199L, 203L, 201L, 
202L, 204L, 198L, 200L, 199L, 201L, 200L, 199L, 198L, 203L, 204L, 
198L, 201L, 203L, 204L, 203L, 204L, 202L, 201L, 200L, 199L, 198L, 
203L, 204L, 202L, 198L, 199L, 200L, 201L, 198L, 199L, 201L, 203L, 
204L, 199L, 198L, 201L, 203L, 204L, 203L, 200L, 199L, 198L, 204L, 
202L, 201L, 198L, 203L, 201L, 204L, 199L, 198L, 201L, 203L, 204L, 
201L, 198L, 203L, 204L, 201L, 198L, 203L, 204L, 198L, 199L, 201L, 
203L, 204L, 200L, 198L, 199L, 201L, 202L, 203L, 204L, 200L, 204L, 
200L, 203L, 201L, 199L, 198L, 204L, 202L, 201L, 199L, 198L, 203L, 
200L, 201L, 202L, 203L, 204L, 200L, 199L, 198L, 200L, 204L, 203L, 
202L, 201L, 199L, 198L, 204L, 203L, 202L, 201L, 199L, 200L, 198L, 
199L, 201L, 204L, 203L, 202L, 200L, 203L, 202L, 201L, 199L, 204L, 
198L, 204L, 203L, 202L, 201L, 200L, 198L, 198L, 199L, 201L, 200L, 
203L, 204L, 202L, 198L, 199L, 200L, 202L, 204L, 201L), PH = c(7.22, 
7.2, 6.9, 7.11, 7.01, 7.03, 7.03, 7.17, 6.99, 6.99, 6.85, 6.84, 
6.88, 6.95, 6.94, 7.04, 6.93, 6.93, 7.21, 7.23, 7.19, 7.25, 7.07, 
7.09, 7.09, 7.16, 7.43, 7.47, 7.41, 7.08, 7.05, 7.07, 7.1, 7.15, 
7.12, 7.16, 7.25, 7.2, 7.26, 7.49, 7.62, 7.12, 7.16, 7.44, 7.3, 
7.11, 7.2, 7.21, 7.14, 7.06, 6.66, 7.28, 7.29, 7.42, 7.22, 7.63, 
7.52, 7.35, 7.05, 7.23, 7.16, 7.32, 7.3, 7.22, 7.19, 7.34, 7.55, 
7.27, 7.26, 7.36, 7.42, 7.35, 7.2, 7.3, 7.24, 7.19, 7.45, 7.5, 
7.36, 7.21, 7.34, 7.25, 7.11, 7.01, 7.03, 6.95, 7.36, 7.3, 7.2, 
7.21, 7.2, 7.21, 7.23, 7.16, 7.12, 7.19, 7.29, 7.19, 7.14, 5.31, 
6.99, 7.15, 7.16, 6.87, 7.12, 7.3, 7.67, 7.28, 7.54, 7.29, 7.45, 
7.44, 7.17, 7.13, 7.13, 7.14, 7.68, 7.6, 6.89, 7.42, 7.3, 7.4, 
7.28, 7.29, 7.23, 7.21, 7.44, 7.21, 7.4, 7.26, 7.48, 7.29, 7.33, 
7.08, 7.27, 7.57, 7.28, 7.69, 7.44, 7.31, 7.36, 7.4, 7.36, 7.47, 
7.75, 7.5, 6.97, 7.08, 6.96, 7.1, 7.07, 7.13, 7.38, 7.11, 7.22, 
7.19, 7.13, 7.29, 7.12, 7.03, 7.09, 7.23, 7, 7.11, 7.85, 7.8, 
7.36, 8.01, 7.03, 7.33, 7.32, 7.31, 7.56, 7.27, 7.32, 7.08, 7.07
), EH = c(100L, 470L, 462L, 1L, 427L, -6L, 118L, -24L, 57L, -12L, 
93L, 136L, 119L, 101L, 128L, 32L, 35L, 137L, -4L, 107L, 84L, 
79L, -1L, 71L, 108L, 5L, 467L, 450L, 470L, 11L, 111L, 80L, -2L, 
160L, -16L, 148L, 215L, 103L, -45L, 260L, 300L, 141L, 288L, 335L, 
64L, 85L, 120L, 86L, 129L, 72L, 144L, 49L, 108L, 335L, 170L, 
285L, 308L, 5L, 49L, 108L, 335L, 5L, 308L, 285L, 170L, 78L, 282L, 
145L, 70L, 146L, 325L, 92L, 137L, 94L, 137L, 51L, 283L, 290L, 
77L, 116L, 287L, 143L, 87L, 81L, 129L, 117L, 243L, 29L, 114L, 
-5L, 105L, 131L, 121L, 60L, 88L, 127L, 69L, 62L, 122L, 64L, 450L, 
128L, 45L, 117L, 340L, 287L, 436L, 165L, 406L, 122L, 175L, 441L, 
136L, 325L, 81L, 148L, 285L, 118L, 209L, 186L, 204L, 433L, 176L, 
153L, 420L, 182L, 380L, 150L, 195L, 379L, 455L, 143L, 391L, 379L, 
178L, 339L, 165L, 435L, 125L, 161L, 128L, 416L, 173L, 381L, 420L, 
130L, 333L, 153L, 151L, 79L, 246L, 428L, 147L, 330L, 161L, 217L, 
155L, 75L, 139L, 104L, 164L, 167L, 302L, 69L, 223L, 226L, 206L, 
331L, 330L, 485L, 237L, 111L, 291L, 386L, 64L, 155L, 170L)), .Names = c("TIME", 
"GAUGE_ID", "PH", "EH"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-177L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `aggregate` in base R and a little date formatting "magic" to calculate this.

For every month-year, you could use:

```
aggregate(PH~format(TIME, "%Y-%m"), data=df, FUN=mean)
```

which returns

```
   format(TIME, "%Y-%m")       PH
1                2000-07 7.220000
2                2000-12 7.070000
3                2001-01 7.020000
4                2001-08 7.045000
5                2001-11 6.880000
6                2002-03 6.960000
7                2002-07 7.220000
...
31               2010-05 7.207143
32               2010-11 7.096667
33               2013-04 7.528571
34               2014-03 7.268333
```

For every month, across years, you could use

```
aggregate(PH~format(TIME, "%m"), data=df, FUN=mean)
```

which returns

```
   format(TIME, "%m")       PH
1                  01 7.221429
2                  02 7.285000
3                  03 7.284167
4                  04 7.428571
5                  05 7.255000
6                  06 7.252632
7                  07 7.220000
8                  08 7.134444
9                  09 7.299167
10                 10 7.102500
11                 11 7.048214
12                 12 7.250000
```

As the column names may not be what you want you want, you could wrap `aggregate` in `setNames` and provide nicer column names or do so in the next line.

```
setNames(aggregate(PH~format(TIME, "%m"), data=df, FUN=mean), c("months", "meanPH"))
```

---

you can easily add more columns by including `cbind` into `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(cbind(PH, EH)~format(TIME, "%m"), data=df, FUN=mean)
```

alternatively, you could use the standard interface to `aggregate`, where a list in the second argument determines the grouping.

```
aggregate(df[c("PH", "EH")], list(format(df$TIME, "%m")), FUN=mean)
```

Comment: Is there a way to let aggregate return a `data.frame` with the pH means as well as the EH means (another column in the example data)?

Comment: Otherwise it's clear how to do it via `cbind`: `cbind(aggregate(PH ~ format(TIME, "%Y-%m"), data=df, FUN=mean), (aggregate(EH ~ format(TIME, "%Y-%m"), data=df, FUN=mean)[,2])`.

Comment: See my edit at the bottom. It incorporates `cbind` into the `aggregate` function using the formula interface to `aggregate` or shows an alternative to the formula interface.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to calculate the mean of a given column for every month, you can try with [data.table](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/data.table.pdf), I think it would be easier.

```
library(data.table)
df <- as.data.table(df)
df[, .(meanByMonth = mean(PH)), by = month(TIME)][order(month)]

    month meanByMonth
 1:     1    7.221429
 2:     2    7.285000
 3:     3    7.284167
 4:     4    7.428571
 5:     5    7.255000
 6:     6    7.252632
 7:     7    7.220000
 8:     8    7.134444
 9:     9    7.299167
10:    10    7.102500
11:    11    7.048214
12:    12    7.250000
```

P.S. This [cheat sheet](https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/img/blog/data+table+cheat+sheet.pdf) is very useful.

Comment: It's amazing what `data.table` can do! I have to study it as soon as possible!

Comment: Yeah, it is. I have edited the answer with a cheat sheet that I find particularly useful when working with data.tables. I hope it helps.