# How do i find week number from an arbitrary start date in R?

Tags: r, lubridate

How do I find the week number from an arbitrary start date in R.  Let's say I want my start date to be august 1st.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14454476/get-the-difference-between-dates-in-terms-of-weeks-months-quarters-and-years

Comment: How about this: `difftime("2020-08-21", Sys.Date(), units = "weeks")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `difftime` for this:

```
difftime("2020-08-21", Sys.Date(), units = "weeks")
# Time difference of 30.45238 weeks
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `lubridate`, you can do:

```
interval(today(), dmy("21-08-2020"))/weeks(1)

[1] 30.42857
```

Or from the date of interest to another date:

```
interval(dmy("21-08-2020"), dmy("21-09-2020"))/weeks(1)

[1] 4.428571
```