# Time difference between quarters

Tags: r, date, date-formatting, date-difference

I am currently working with dates in R and need to calculate the time difference between two quarters.  I have used the `zoo` library to transform my dates into quarterly format, but I am struggling to calculate the difference between my dates.

Here is a sample code for reproducability:

```
sample_dataframe <- data.frame(First_Purchase_date = c(as.Date("2020-01-15"), as.Date("2019-02-10"),as.Date("2018-12-24")),Recent_Purchase_date = c(as.Date("2020-06-20"), as.Date("2020-10-10"), as.Date("2019-05-26")))

library(zoo)
#using zoo library to transform my dates into quarters
sample_dataframe$First_purchase_quarter <- as.yearqtr((sample_dataframe$First_Purchase_date), "%Y-%m-%d")
sample_dataframe$Recent_Purchase_quarter <- as.yearqtr((sample_dataframe$Recent_Purchase_date), "%Y-%m-%d")
```

What I want to achieve is to **subtract** Recent_Purchase_quarter  from First_purchase_quarter to get a time difference in quarters.

So if Recent_Purchase_quarter  is *2019 Q2* and First_Purchase_quarter is *2018 Q4* the result should be **2**.

What would be the easiest way to get the time difference in quarters as described above?

Comment: This post covers ways to calculate difference in terms of weeks, months, quarters and years https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14454476/get-the-difference-between-dates-in-terms-of-weeks-months-quarters-and-years

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#using zoo library to transform my dates into quarters
sample_dataframe$First_purchase_quarter <- as.yearqtr((sample_dataframe$First_Purchase_date), "%Y-%m-%d")
sample_dataframe$Recent_Purchase_quarter <- as.yearqtr((sample_dataframe$Recent_Purchase_date), "%Y-%m-%d")

sample_dataframe$diff <- (sample_dataframe[, 4] - sample_dataframe[, 3]) * 4
head(sample_dataframe$diff)
[1] 1 7 2
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks a lot for your speedy reply! It seemed to have done the trick! Could you please elaborate why I have to multiply the calculation by 4 in order to get to the desired outcome? Thank you!

Comment: `yearqtr` thinks in years, so a timedifference of 0.25 equals one quarter, that's why it is multiplied by 4. You can find more information on it by running `?yearqtr`